# Using Google Play Game services in windows phone 8 and windows 8

Tags: google-play-games, google-api-dotnet-client

Google Game Services 1.6 beta (.Net library) is available from Nuget for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 games. However when setting up the leaderboards and achievements in Google Developer Console, it only allows to associate an Android game, iOS game or Web game. How does one actually go about using Game Services in WP8 and W8 games?

Answer (score 0):

The `Link another App` button now allows you to select `Other platform` (I guess they added it recently).